# Autocomplete list for group of text boxes

Tags: jquery

From my particular question I have got answer for implementing auto complete list..but issue is when I clicked on any suggested it blanks my input box. I have input boxes with class `track`. My function that I used for on blur event is..

```
<input name="track[]" type="text" class="track" maxlength="150"/>
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
  <img src="images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 50px;" alt="upArrow" />
  <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<script>
$('input.track').keyup(function() {
var poetname = $(this).val();
if(poetname.length == 0) {
    // Hide the suggestion box.
    $(this).parent().find('#suggestions').hide();
} 
else {
    $.ajax({
        url: "rpc.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {queryString: poetname},
        context: this, // i.e. the text box
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.length >0) {
                $(this).parent().find('#suggestions').show();
                $(this).parent().find('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
});

$('input.track').blur(function() {
    $(this).val( );
    $(this).parent().find('.suggestionsBox').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: The code can't (and doesn't) do what you describe. Please provide a more complete code example including the parts that actually update the input box. FWIW, your `$(this).val();` is currently doing nothing.

Comment: I have editted on key event for autosuggestion list. Hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

Two things going on here--

1. I'm not sure you're capturing the event you want to capture. I can't tell what the use case is, but you seem to be saying that you are listening for click on a suggestion. Yet, you are not capturing any clicks anywhere on the suggestion box.
2. The blur event is only hiding the `.suggestionsBox` and if that's what it's meant to do then it's working fine! The `$(this).val();` line isn't doing anything useful. The JavaScript is actually finding that value, but it's then not doing anything with it.

No matter what, I'm not seeing the input box being blanked.

Here's a fiddle that uses a test echo for the Ajax: http://jsfiddle.net/xXF9v/